# Pandas read csv with formatting errors

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to load a csv file where blank spaces are used as tabulation, like this:

`2021-08-27 12:21:28.259 2021-08-25 17:36:52.045     1,9253   -2,0298   -1,3901   356,6895  111,0229  893,0664  -162,1033  -35,9802  131,6052`

BUT there are some lines with bad formatting, where values are too big, and there is **no blank space** between some values:

`2021-08-27 12:21:28.350 2021-08-25 17:36:52.155    -4,7617   -5,2017   -8,0220 -1484,8022 -127,9907-1999,7559    99,7943  -55,4700 -109,0063`

So when I import the csv with `pd.read_csv()` I get some rows with shifted values.

I tried to edit the text file line by line adding blanks before `-` , but it takes too much time to process.

Is there a fast way to edit the csv while loading?

The **good thing** is that each column start (and ends) always at **fixed positions**, but I did not find any way to load csv in pandas knowing column start/end index

Comment: If this is not a very large file, I'd suggest that you use a python script to split the data using just strings. That would be easier. But if its a very large file, then this is not an option

Comment: Can't you just change the size of blank spaces in csv? `

Comment: @Tharaka Devinda: yes, it is a large file. I have already tried and it takes too much time

Comment: @Julien The problem is not the size of blank spaces, but that they are absent

Comment: Do you always have 4 decimals ? If yes I could work out some regex to perform the substituion.
You can also look at `read_fwf` function of panda for fixed-width-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

Using `read_fwf` like so:

```
pandas.read_fwf('test.csv', header=None)
```

*might work*, but didn't work with the sample of the file provided in the question.

**We can help python** by providing the positions of the fields like so:

```
colspecs = [(0, 10), (11, 23), (24, 34), (35, 47), (48, 58), (58, 68), (68, 78), (78, 89), (89, 99), (99, 109), (109, 120), (120, 130), (130, 140)]
pandas.read_fwf('test.csv', infer_nrows = 13, header=None, colspecs = colspecs)
```

Link to the doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: Awesome! Wasn't aware of this one. Might as well include the link to documentation in your answer: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas-read-fwf

Comment: When I try it with just the OP's example two lines, it fails to separate `-127,9907-1999,7559` into two columns, even when specifying `infer_nrows=13`. Hopefully it would succeed on a larger dataset if at least one of the rows is better separated. Otherwise, we can still use the `widths` optional argument to manually specify where to split the columns.

Comment: You're right @Stef, I'm working on the `colspecs` to provide the right answer.

Comment: If you trust my counting: `[0, 11, 24, 35, 48, 58, 68, 78, 89, 99, 109, 120, 130, 140]` (this is the result of `itertools.accumulate` on the widths I used in my answer)

Comment: I wouldn't say "Using `read_fwf` like so [...] will not work". It's likely that it would work on a bigger dataset, where at least one of the first 100 rows can help separate the two annoying columns. But we have only two rows to test it, and they are not enough for pandas. And when it does work, it's probably best to let `read_fwf` infer the columns, rather than hardcode them.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer describes how to parse the file manually. A preferable solution is to use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) instead.*

Since all columns are the same size, you can use list comprehensions to split the columns:

```py
# data.csv
2021-08-27 12:21:28.350 2021-08-25 17:36:52.155    -4,7617   -5,2017   -8,0220 -1484,8022 -127,9907-1999,7559    99,7943  -55,4700 -109,0063
2021-08-27 12:21:28.259 2021-08-25 17:36:52.045     1,9253   -2,0298   -1,3901   356,6895  111,0229  893,0664  -162,1033  -35,9802  131,6052
```

```py
import itertools # accumulate

def load_file(filename, widths):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    table = []
    for line in f:
      table.append([line[p:p+w] for w,p in zip(widths, itertools.accumulate(widths, initial=0))])
  return table

print(load_file('data.csv', [11,13,11,13,10,10,10,11,10,10,11,10,10]))
# [['2021-08-27 ', '12:21:28.350 ', '2021-08-25 ', '17:36:52.155 ', '   -4,7617', '   -5,2017', '   -8,0220', ' -1484,8022', ' -127,9907', '-1999,7559', '    99,7943', '  -55,4700', ' -109,0063'],
#  ['2021-08-27 ', '12:21:28.259 ', '2021-08-25 ', '17:36:52.045 ', '    1,9253', '   -2,0298', '   -1,3901', '   356,6895', '  111,0229', '  893,0664', '  -162,1033', '  -35,9802', '  131,6052']]
```

Then you can load the resulting table into `pandas` directly and hope that it parses all the numbers and dates correctly; or if you try to parse the values more manually, then `.strip()` will be a lot of help to remove all the trailing whitespace.

Comment: Does this solution slow down processing time?

Comment: @Ohibò You tell me. I tried it on the data you provided, which only has two lines. Try it on increasingly bigger data and you can tell us how it goes.